ACF - Updating all posts of CPT when a custom field from options page is updated
I have a custom post type - headstones, that contains pricing information in custom fields:

Cost of Stone
Cost of Carving
Cost Total
Retail Price of Stone
Retail Price of Carving
Retail Total

Of the above, the only two I should manually input or update are the Cost of Stone and the Cost of Carving fields. The remaining fields should be calculated based on some custom number fields in an options page.
Currently, I have this working when updating a single headstone, or adding a new one, the calculations are made and the retail prices added.
I can't quite figure out how to update all the headstones if I were to edit a field on the options page. For example, the options page holds the % margin to be added to each headstone cost. If I updated the margin on the options page, I would need to open every headstone and click update for the changes to take effect.
If possible, when the options page fields are saved, I need each headstone to be updated to.
I am also open to another method of doing this, it felt right at the time to store this info in an options page but if the update process can be made easier by storing the info elsewhere then I am happy to do so.

I think there is a problem in your data structure. If the cost depends of other values, it should be calculated when the headstone is displayed and not saved in a meta value.

Thank you for the reply, I had been wondering if that would be the general way to do this but I wasn't sure. So I actually wouldn't store the retail price in a custom field, it would simply be calculated when displayed?
